# Retrieve image as arraybuffer and set it in canvas imageData

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, filereader, arraybuffer

I'm trying all day to retrieve an image with an xhr request as an arraybuffer.
I receive the reply and then I'd like to put the arraybuffer into canvas imagedata, which as far as I know it accepts an Uint8ClampedArray like so:

```
imageData.data.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(arraybuffer));
```

I have failed miserably it's like FileReader cant parse the data when using [FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer).
And although I dont need a base64 solution, it works fine if i use [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL).

Furthermore here is a small **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Laa3jmg9/1/)**

This is not a browser specific issue since I tested it on chrome and on firefox.
I'm specifically interested in parsing the arraybuffer correctly somehow because I'm using web workers with [transferable objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable) and [Datatextures](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Textures/DataTexture) in three.js.

**Source for demo purposes**

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

canvas.width = 45; 
canvas.height = 32; 
canvas.style.position = "fixed"; 
canvas.style.zIndex = 999999;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open( "GET", "https://fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png", true ); xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

xhr.onload = function( e ) {

    var blob = new Blob( [ xhr.response ], { type: "image/png" } );     
    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = function(evt) {

        var imageData = ctx.createImageData(45, 32);

        imageData.data.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(evt.target.result));
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

        console.log("done loading");

    };

    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);

};

document.body.appendChild(canvas); 
xhr.send();
```

PS: I'm using canvas to replicate the bad parsing that perhaps I'm doing because I' missing something.

Comment: I updated the fiddle and the source in the post since there was a small error.

Comment: one is the bytes of the compressed file (the readAsArrayBuffer), one should be RGBA pixel data (the putImageData). fetch a blob and use URL.createObjectURL to turn it into a src of an <img> tag, which you can then draw() on the canvas.

Comment: @dandavis yws I'm familiar with what you said but I'm not going to use it with canvas at the end. I'm just demonstrating the bad parsing with the help of canvas. I'm wondering what should I do  to parse / read the arraybuffer in such a way to be acceptable, in this demo case lets say for for canvas

Comment: @Syd, just like @dandavis said, the first arrayBuffer is the one of the file (with file headers and compressed data etc.) What you need for `putImageData`, is the pixel data. To get it, from a canvas, you first have to uncompress the image, (this is done by passing an `<img>`to the context), draw it on the canvas, then call `getImageData`. An other solution would be to use a javascript parser like [jpgjs](https://github.com/notmasteryet/jpgjs) or [pngjs](https://github.com/arian/pngjs), but I'm not sure if your "bad parsing" demonstration will still be relevant.

Comment: @Kaiido I see I was missing the compression part... do you think tha running a js decode would be more intensive than getting the proper pixel data with another method like the one you mentioned? FYI I'm downloading about 2000 images and storing them in js FileSystem. In a previous implementation i was storing base64 strings. And now i thought to use tranferable objects for my web workers, hence the need for arraybuffers......

Comment: Any code performed by js will be slower than native implementation. I don't know the FileSystem API at all, but from your web workers, you could create Blob versions of the dataURI, and use a FileReader, or even directly make an xhr request to fetch the files from the url. (A small 32*32 canvas with an image I used for tests resulted in a 730 characters string (header included), while the JSON version of the same canvas resulted in a 37977 characters string. If you have to store it, store the compressed version.)